# Sitecore third party form inside the sitecore form

Tags: forms, sitecore

Looking for a way to incorporate a third party form (not a sitecore form) into a sitecore layout.

I suspect it is not working because of the outer sitecore form tag (the one that wraps all content). Problems due to nested form tags (not good).

```
<div><form id="non-sitecore" action="http://third_party.search.com/" method="POST">
  <input ...>...
</form></div>
```

What is the best way to get this type of third party form to work?

Answer (score 4):

Nate,
Your issues isn't specific to Sitecore as it pertains to general ASP.NET web forms as well.

Any easy solution would be to create a page (.html/.aspx/etc...) that has what you need on it. i.e.

```
<div><form id="non-sitecore" action="http://third_party.search.com/" method="POST">
  <input ...>...
</form></div>
```

Then, use an iFrame on your layout/sublayout to bring in your 3rd party 'stuff' that exists on the page you created.

Comment: Got it, and that my be simpler than the way that I have been trying (which is to skip the form tag and submit by jquery post).

Comment: If this gets you to your solution, don't forget to make it as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Best way to render form inside layout render is in Iframe